# switch case not switching when i click the user interface

Tags: javascript, html

please what could be wrong, i am not getting any error in the chrome console

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<i id="repeat" class="fas fa-stop-circle"></i>
</div>
```

javascript

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')
const repeatBtn = wrapper.querySelector('#repeat')
repeatBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
let getClass = repeatBtn.className;

switch(getClass){
    case "fas fa-redo":
        repeatBtn.className = "fas fa-redo";
        break;
    case "fas fa-stop-circle":
        repeatBtn.className = "fas fa-stop-circle";
        break;
    case "fas fa-random":
        repeatBtn.className = "fas fa-random";
        break;
}
})
```

Comment: Your code works. But I would suggest not to use className, rather: **`classList`** and its methods: `add` `remove` `includes` etc....

Comment: Are you sure you don't use multiple `id="repeat"` ID (as the name suggests) should be unique!

Comment: Also, your code makes no sense at all ;) Adding again the same class seems odd: *"If element classes are exactly `fas fa-redo` than make them again `fas fa-redo` "*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no logic in this code that would change the class, so your case statement will always result match `case "fas fa-stop-circle"`. Each of your assignments for `repeatBtn.className` is setting the class to the exact same string the case is matching.

Comment: That's already stated in comments. If it's a typo - than the question can be closed as such ;)